# `arguments` Object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

[Secrets of the JavaScript Ninja](http://www.manning.com/resig/) explains the `arguments` keyword with the `merge()` function:

```
function merge(root){
 for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) { // starts at i = 1, not 0
   for (var key in arguments[i]) {
     root[key] = arguments[i][key];
   }
 }
 return root;
}

var merged = merge(
 {name: "Batou"},
 {city: "Niihama"});
```

Note the assertions:

```
assert(merged.name == "Batou", 
    "The original name is intact.");
assert(merged.city == "Niihama", 
    "And the city has been copied over.");
```

Why does `merged.name` equal `Batou` rather than `undefined`?

Since, as I understand, `merge()` does not look at the first argument in the outer for-loop, how does the `name: Batou` get added to `root`?

Comment: FWIW, `arguments` is not a keyword. It's a normal variable (name).

Comment: So `root.name` is called first in `root [name] = Batou`? I don't understand

Comment: No, `root` *is* the object that is passed as first argument to `merge`, i.e. `{name: "Batou"}`. It *already contains* the property `name`.

Comment: perhaps it's due to inexperience with `arguments`, but the `merge` function above seems confusing to me. Is it an acceptable/passes code review practice in JS?

Comment: I updated the title - thanks, Felix King.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`root` itself is the first argument, thus we don't need to add whatever members is in it to itself.

Comment: IMO, `target` would have been a more descriptive name than `root`.

Answer (score 1):

It's already in `root`. That's the first parameter